# Retrive entire column to a new file if it matches from list of another file

Tags: bash, matching

I have a huge file and I need to retrieve specific columns from File1 which is ~ 200000 rows and ~ 1000 Columns if it matches with the list of file2. (Prefer Bash over R )
for example my dummy data files are as follows,

file1

```
gene    s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
a      1    2   1   2   1
b      2    3   2   3   3
c      1    1   1   1   1
d      1    1   2   2   2
```

and file2

```
sample
s4
s3
s7
s8
```

My desired output is

```
gene       s3   s4  
    a       1   2   
    b       2   3   
    c       1   1   
    d       2   2
```

likewise, i have 3 different file2 and i have to pick different samples from the same file1 into a new file. 
I would be very greatful if you guys can provide me with your valuable suggestions

P.S: I am a Biologist, i have very little coding experience

Regards

Ateeq

Comment: Thanks, Cyrus for letting me know that Novice are not allowed here. but I think I fall under Enthusiastic group, if not professional. anyways, i used the following code, awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' list_genes.csv file2.csv.....for this i need to transpose the data which i want to avoid.

Comment: Since I guess you haven't done it yet: take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take a look at SO's [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: thanks Cyrus! its really helpful!!!

Comment: Novices are allowed and encouraged, but if you really want anyone trying to help you, give the information as easy as possible to work with. Nobody will translate the images into text to try posible solutions. But if you give text (that can be copied and pasted) chances are many people will try to help you.

Comment: I have removed the image, and created a dummy file and data, since whenever i paste it is forcing me to save the data as an image. Apologies !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1 
gene    s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
a      1    2   1   2   1
b      2    3   2   3   3
c      1    1   1   1   1
d      1    1   2   2   2
$ cat file2
gene
s4
s3
s8
s7
$ cat a 
awk '
NR == FNR {
  columns[ NR ] = $0
  printf "%s\t", $0
  next
}
FNR == 1 { 
  print ""
  split( $0, headers ) 
  for (x = 1 ; x <= length(headers) ; x++ ) 
  { 
    aheaders[  headers[x]] = x
  }
  next
}
{
  for ( x = 1 ; x <= length( columns ) ; x++ ) 
  {
    if (length( aheaders[ columns[x]  ] ) == 0 )
      printf "N/A\t"
    else
      printf "%s\t" , $aheaders[ columns[x] ]
  }
  print ""
}
' $*

$ ./a file2 file1 | column -t

gene  s4  s3  s8   s7
a     2   1   N/A  N/A
b     3   2   N/A  N/A
c     1   1   N/A  N/A
d     2   2   N/A  N/A
```

The above should get you on your way.  It's an extremely optimistic program and no negative testing was performed.

Awk is a tool that applies a set of commands to every line of every file that matches an expression.  In general, the awk script has the form:

```
<pattern> <command>
```

There are three such pairs above.  Each needs a little explanation:

```
NR == FNR {
  columns[ NR ] = $0
  printf "%s\t", $0
  next
}
```

NR == FNR is a awk'ism.  NR is the record number and FNR is the record number in the current file.  NR is always increasing but FNR resets to 1 when awk parses the next file.  NR==FNR is an idiom that is only true when parsing the first file.

I've designed the awk program to read the columns file first (you are calling this file2).  File2 has a list of columns to output.  As you can see, we are storing each line in the first file (file2) into an array called columns. We are also printing the columns out as we read them.  In order to avoid newlines after each column name (since we want all the column headers to be on the same line), we use printf which doesn't output a newline (as opposed to print which does).

The 'next' at the end of the stanza tells awk to read the next line in the file without processing any of the other stanzas.   After all, we just want to read the first file.

In summary, the first stanza remembers the column names (and order) and prints them out on a single line (without a newline).

The second "stanza":

```
FNR == 1 { 
  print ""
  split( $0, headers ) 
  for (x = 1 ; x <= length(headers) ; x++ ) 
  { 
    aheaders[  headers[x]] = x
  }
  next
}
```

FNR==1 will match on the first line of any file.  Due to the next in the previous stanza, we'll only hit this stanza when we are on the first line of the second file (file1).  The first print "" statement adds the newline that was missing from the first stanza.  Now the line with the column headers is complete.

The split command takes the  first parameter, $0, the current line  and splits it according to whitespace.  We know the current line is the first line and has the column headers in it.  The split command writes to an array named in the second parameter , headers.  Now headers[1] = "gene" and headers[2] = "s4" , headers[3] = "s3", etc.

We're going to need to map the column names to the column numbers.  The next bit of code takes each header value and creates an aheaders entry.  aheders is an associative array that maps column header names to the column number.

```
aheaders["gene"] = 1
aheaders["s1"] = 2
aheaders["s2"] = 3
aheaders["s3"] = 4
aheaders["s4"] = 5
aheaders["s5"] = 6
```

When we're done making the aheaders array, the next command tells awk to skip to the next line of the input.  From this point on, only the third stanza is going to have a true  condition.

```
{
  for ( x = 1 ; x <= length( columns ) ; x++ ) 
  {
    if (length( aheaders[ columns[x]  ] ) == 0 )
      printf "N/A\t"
    else
      printf "%s\t" , $aheaders[ columns[x] ]
  }
  print ""
}
```

The third stanza has no explicit .  Awk will process this as always true.  So this last  is executed for every line of the second file.

At this point, we want to print the columns that are specified in columns array.  We walk through each element of the array in order.  The first time through the loop, columns[1] = "gene_symbol".  This gives us:

```
printf "%s\t" , $aheaders[ "gene" ]
```

And since aheaders["gene"] = 1  this gives us:

```
printf "%s\t" , $1
```

And awk understands $1 to be the first field (or column) in the input line.  Thus the first column is passed to printf which outputs the value with a tab (\t) appended.

The loop then executes another time with x=2 and columns[2]="s4".  This results in the following print executing:

```
printf "%s\t" , $5
```

This prints the fifth column followed by a tab. The next iteration:

```
columns[3] = "s3"
aheaders["s3"] = 4
```

Which results in:

```
printf "%s\t" , $4
```

That is, the fourth field is output.

The next iteration we hit a failure situation:

```
columns[4] = "s8"
aheaders["s8"] = ''
```

In this case, the length( aheaders[ columns[x]  ]  ) == 0 is true so we just print out a placeholder - something to tell the operator their input may be invalid:

```
printf "N/A\t"
```

The same is output when we process the last columns[x] value "s7".

Now, since there are no more entries in columns, the loop exists and we hit the final print:

```
print ""
```

The empty string is provided to print because print by itself defaults to print $0 - the entire line.

At this point, awk reads the next line out of file1 hits the third   block again (only).  Thus awk continues until the second file is completely read.

Comment: You meant ["without further ado"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/without+further+ado). But you just don't need that for your answer.